# Edit Paypal Express Review Page

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, phtml, paypal-express

I have made changes to my paypal/express/reivew.phtml. The problem is they are not showing up. Cleared cache multiple times. Copied the file and put it under my theme as well.

I have closed the browser and gone back into the checkout process to see if the edits worked...still no dice.

Any ideas at where the correct file to edit is. Everything I read, I am in the right place, I just don't see my changes.

Thank you

Comment: please enable template hints in admin and see.

Answer (score 2):

**The file you are looking for resides on**

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/paypal/express/review.phtml
>
> But before making changes to it,its good practice of overwriting it to
>   you theme and making changes there.
>
> Hope, this is what you are looking for.

Comment: That is exactly where I am making changes. They are not showing even though I have made changes to that file. I also have copied that same directory into my theme folder, still no luck.